# Error running IIS-Express in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis-express

I have an API in Visual Studio and when I run it in IIS Express, it worked fine.

Today I did the same thing but it's not working. I believe that my IP address is correct so I don't think the issue is there, I'm also running it as administrator. I even went to the event view and it says that

> The worker process failed to initialize correctly

and therefore could not be started. I'll show u the images below if anyone had this problem or knows how to fix it please tell me.

I've also tried to reinstall Visual Studio but its still not working

[error in event viewr1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUxKP.png)

[error in event viewer2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKOrP.png)

[error in Visual Studio when I try to run the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeUIs.png)

i've tried to repair the IIS Express and this is what pops up
[Repair Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWw9P.png)

If it helps I'm using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Try to repair IIS Express in Control Panel | Programs.

Comment: i've tried to do so but its not letting me i'll put the screenshot of what pops up

Comment: Install iis express from the https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264

Comment: I've uninstalled my current and installed that version but the error its still the same although I can now repair the IIS Express

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but with a web service: I simply changed the port the web app was using.

Right click the solution in the Solution Explorer tab, click "Properties," then "Move to Web," and change the port on the project URL.